# MTA for windows to use for PHP Sendmail

Tags: php, mta, processmaker

I was trying to setup Processmaker on my Win7 system. For sending Email I want to use PHP's Sendmail(). But for that I need to install some MTA on my machine and need to configure php.ini for it. Can someone please guide me on MTA thing. 
I am follwoing this link for email setup.
(http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/2.0/Email_-_Settings)

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd suggest using the phpmailer option (hm, a swiftmailer option would be even better imho) there's e.g. http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/ (or simpler http://glob.com.au/sendmail/ )

It takes an email like a sendmail mail submission agent would but doesn't inject it into the local MTA queue. Instead is sends the mail via smpt to another mailing system (gmail e.g.).
phpmailer would do more or less the same thing but without spawing a new process.